# Nested addition of attributes (NetworkX) / dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension, networkx, dictionary-comprehension

Hoping this title is not too unclear, I'd like to add do a nested dictionary comprehension, with the underlying goal of adding node attributes i NetworkX using loops, with output similar to this:

```
[('x1', {'a': 0}, {'b': 5}, {'c': 10} ),
 ('x2', {'a': 1}, {'b': 6}, {'c': 11} ),
 ...]
```

What I thought might work:

```
a = [ ( 'x%d' % h, {'1st': i}, {'2nd': j},  {'3rd': k} ) 
      for h in range(1,17), for i in range(0,6), 
      for j in range(5,11), for k in range(10,16)  ]
```

But this returned "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

EDIT: I will ask the previously mentioned second part in a separate question - thanks so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are syntax errors in your code: the commas before `for` are invalid. You just need to remove them as mentioned in [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49541389/9565387). However, it will behave like nested `for` loops, while you want `h, i, j, k` to increase simultaneously. The desired output could be achieved as follows:

```
[ ( 'x%d' % h, {'1st': i}, {'2nd': j},  {'3rd': k} )
  for h, i, j, k in zip(range(1,17), range(0,6), range(5,11), range(10,16))]
```

Or even better:

```
[ ( 'x%d' % (i+1), {'1st': i}, {'2nd': i+5},  {'3rd': i+10} ) for i in range(6)]
```

Comment: Thanks @ducminh, the first part was helpful, and I prefer it over the second part for readability reasons as well as flexibility in defining the ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `,` between the for loops:

```
a = [ ('x%d' % h, {'1st': i}, {'2nd': j}, {'3rd': k}) for h in range(1,17) for i in range(0,6) for j in range(5,11) for k in range(10,16) ]
```

Comment: By the way with a line that long it will be more readable to just write it in a normal sequential way

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I will try to solve the second part of the puzzle now :)